# Sonar-scanner in jenkins error does not match any configured installation

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I installed Sonarqube plugin in Jenkins,
already configured the sonarqube server and sonarqube scanner from the Jenkins configuration:

but when I ran the pipeline I got this error:

***ERROR: SonarQube installation defined in this job (sonarqube) does not match any configured installation. Number of installations that can be configured: 1.***

Here is the configuration:
[image: sonarqube server config]
[image: sonarqube scanner config]

What causing the error above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were apparently requesting the use of installation "sonarqube", but the configured name is "SonarQubeScanner".  Those don't match.  I also note that calling it "SonarQubeScanner" is not quite right.  That is an installation of SonarQube, not the scanner.  It doesn't make sense to use the same name for SonarQube installations and SonarQube scanners.  They are different things.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try on Monday and let you know the result.